# Ads in a free ap that require outside subscription (like netflix)

Tags: ios

Does it go against any sort of TOS with apple if you display ads in a free app, when that app requires an outside subscription service?  Like netflix.

This isn't totally a programming questions, so if no one knows, or doesn't want to answer, is there a site or location I could go to in order to find out?

Comment: I don't know if there is any restrictions set forth for the usage of ads, other than the content of those ads must be appropriate, I would assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has no restrictions against ads in free applications. There are several ad-supported apps which exist.

However, using location data of the user for advertising **might** lead to the app not being approved.